# flask hidden input field with csrf_token is visible in elements pane

Tags: flask, input, csrf

I'm making a flask app and I'm a bit of an amateur, especially what security is concerned. I created a secret key in my terminal using

```
os.urandom(24)
```

Then I've put the key that was produced in a separate config file.

```
config.py
import os
class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY= os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or '\x01\x14#\x15\xf7\x90\xc8\xdd\x99Q}b\x82~[v'
```

I've built a form that posts data and I've added a hidden input field that holds a secret key with flask_wtf and wtforms. I've followed instructions and the input field is indeed hidden, there's a key inside it. All hunky dory. In several posts I see the exact same input and output so I guess it's allright. But the input field with the secret key is visible in the element's pane. One only needs to open up the dev tools to see it sitting there. Is that safe? Isn't the secret key supposed to be deeply hidden? How does this really work? Or have I done something wrong?

```
<form action="" method="post"  >
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
</form>
```

this produces

```
<form actions="" method="post">
   <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="IjkyODk2NDQ5Y2I5ZTM1NWIzMGIwMjg3ODhkMDVkZjU2OTNlOGM1Nzki.YOXJcg.xepMZGrYqvcwSnXtnzGl31UhASk">
</form>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's how it's supposed to be. The secret key is there in the hidden field, but also in the user's session (unique per user). So when a user submits the form, the value of that hidden field is compared against the value of the same field in the session. If there's a mismatch the submission gets rejected.

Comment: Right, and the data of the session is safely stored on the server and cannot be messed with. Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: You are welcome. I believe by default the session is not on the server but in an encrypted cookie on the client. What's on the server is a secret key to decrypt this data.

Comment: Good to know, I've noticed that the value of the key changes each time I refresh the page, so I suppose that is happening because the secret key on the server is encrypting that cookie each time.